# Very top bar with battery life and wifi status not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-titlebar

Sorry for the simple question but I cant figure out whats going on with this. The theme of my layout is set to NoTitleBar and the gui shows that slim bar where you pull notifications down from but when I run my app on my galaxy nexus its not there. It just shows white space where that bar is supposed to be. How do I make this bar with battery life and such show up. thanks

Comment: figured it out. Just had to remove "Fullscreen" from the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

check your activity declared in mainfest file ..put your theme as no title bar in your activity in manifest file..if problem is not solve then put your code for better understanding